# Iron wire as DC Power Filter

Tags: skin-effect

Since Iron has a skin depth of 220 micrometres at 60 Hz, and much lower at higher frequencies, how well would it perform as a DC power filter? Would there be any electrical downsides to using it as such (apart from DC resistance)? (I'm sure there are probably mechanical downsides, so this is more of a hypothetical)

Comment: The biggest down-side is RUST and softer with more iron.  Then as L increases so does R rise and become lossy for DC.  Then if you plate it, that shunts the high mu inductance.

Comment: Iron actually works well in power filters, but as a magnetic core not a conductor.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Are you describing a typical inductor with an iron core?

Comment: @HarrySvensson powdered iron core yes. Not sure what the OP is talking about though...

Comment: @BruceAbbott I meant just using Iron wires to connect devices to their power source

Answer (score 2):

If we ignore capacitance, inductance, transmission line effects, etc...

The skin-depth is proportional to square root of the reciprocal of the frequency ratio, 0.3162 per decade, or -10 dB per decade. The conductance is proportional to the skin-depth cross-section.

On the graph below, the frequency is normalized, 1 is where the skin-depth is equal to the radius. the softness near the corner is because the cross-section is radius squared, not because of phase. Far from the corner the cross-section is approximately proportional to the skin-depth.

Conclusion: It is a lousy filter, the falloff is half as much as a traditional first order filter. Changing the frequency requires a physical (radius) change. Iron will rust. There are no advantages that I can think of.

[image]

Comment: "*The skin-depth is proportional to square root of the frequency ratio*" is slightly misleading, as it is proportional to \$\sqrt{\frac{1}{f}}\$, calling that for "*frequency ratio*", hmm, I'd call it the square root of the *period*. Or just proportional to the equation I just wrote. - "*Changing the frequency requires a geometry change*", why?

Comment: @HarrySvensson - agree with the first comment, I updated the description.

Comment: @HarrySvensson - yes, radius change would be better description.

Comment: It's interesting that this "half pole" effect (-10db/decade compared to -20db/decade) that the skin-effect results in is not dependent on the material. So I presume a copper wire would have similar low pass filtering mechanics due to the skin-effect as an iron wire. Though, maybe a copper wire has a higher cutoff frequency. But as you've said in your post, it's still a lousy filter.